# Creating a branch per version is comunity "accepted" in github?

Tags: git, github

I was looking at some github repositories and I just arrived here:

https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng

As far as I understand, this guy is creating a new branch for every version of his tool and maintaining the master branch with the last version. I just want to know if this is an accepted practice by the git/github comunity and users.

I internally store my code revision the same way, and I want to know if it is a "good practise" so I could also use it in my repositories.

Comment: The linked repo seems to be converted from svn or something, so it inherited branched which used to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is subjective. Practices to maintain software on github vary from organization to organization.

There is no pre-defined practice for software maintenance on Github.

Some organization creates tag for each version of software with stable version in master branch and development version in other branch namely `devel or test`, some other prefers creating separate branch for each version and maintains latest release in master branch. Some other may prefer having separate branch for each version and stable software in master branch and latest version in devel branch.

Each practices have pros and cons. While one may give you convenience to maintain codebase easily, other may make you life easier to release cycle, and so on.

It depends on your requirements and convenience to maintain software. 
Have a look at these popular open source projects on github -

1. [ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby)
2. [npm](https://github.com/npm/npm)
3. [django](https://github.com/django/django)
4. [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails)
5. [laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)
6. [Go](https://github.com/golang/go)

Analyse and choose practice that suits your requirements and is as per your convenience.

Hope it helps you decide!